# youtube-dl download videos with formatid

Tags: python, youtube, embedding, youtube-dl, python-embedding

> ------------------------------Format Numbers----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> - 249          webm       audio only DASH audio   52k , opus @ 50k, 629.08KiB
> - 250          webm       audio only DASH audio   69k , opus @ 70k, 811.98KiB
> - 171          webm       audio only DASH audio  110k , vorbis@128k, 1.27MiB
> - 140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  128k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k, 1.56MiB
> - 251          webm       audio only DASH audio  138k , opus @160k, 1.53MiB
> - 278          webm       254x144    144p   82k , webm container, vp9, 13fps, video only, 772.69KiB
> - 242          webm       400x226    240p  101k , vp9, 25fps, video only, 884.56KiB
> - 160          mp4        254x144    144p  112k , avc1.4d400c, 13fps, video only, 1.31MiB
> - 133          mp4        400x226    240p  265k , avc1.4d400d, 25fps, video only, 2.92MiB
> - 17           3gp        176x144    small , mp4v.20.3,  mp4a.40.2@ 24k
> - 36           3gp        320x180    small , mp4v.20.3,  mp4a.40.2
> - 18           mp4        400x226    medium , avc1.42001E,  mp4a.40.2@ 96k
> - 43           webm       640x360    medium , vp8.0,  vorbis@128k (best)

I want use format numbers in a program like this

```
import youtube_dl

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc"
ydl_opts = {
    'verbose': True,
    'format': 'bestaudio/best', #maybe like this 'formatid'= 22
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s',
    'noplaylist': True,
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
```

how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want format 22, then indeed, pass in a `format` key of `22`. You can use `/best` to fall back to the best video format if 22 is not available:

```
ydl_opts = {
    'format': '22/best',
    ...
```